# Regular expression parsing

Tags: regex

My input is a regular expression, for example: `[0-]\sbla\scd\s\^a`
I want to get the unchangeable strings. The output for the example would be:

```
bla
cd
^a
```

Does anyone know about a program which does that, source code would be helpful. (it's not homework :)

Comment: What about `a[b]c`, should it return `a c`, or `abc`? And what about `ab{0}c`, should it return `a c` or `ac`?

Comment: @Sebastian or `abc` as that is an unchangable string. or what about `(ab){3}` should that be nothing, `ab` or `ababab`?

Comment: You may be able to regex split the string based on characters with special meaning, then take the remaining tokens and parse them as string literals. e.g. (and not bullet-proof) split based on this: `(?<!\\)(\[.*?\]|\\[abBdDefnrsStv]|\x[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|\^|\$)`

Comment: In short, I think we can conclude that this is not that trivial a problem, and will require proper parsing of the regex. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the code of a regex parser. It would get the "unchangeable" strings while parsing. If it expose the parsing tree, you can have what you want. it would be better than writing your own parser ...

Try the source of something like libregex :)

my two cents.